# Bokeh Vertical Bar Chart

Tags: charts, bokeh

I am currently investigating Bokeh as an alternative to Seaborn but I cannot get the vertical bar chart to work.

I want to produce a vertical bar chart showing the sum of 2018 by 'Cylinders'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('table1.csv')

df.head(5)

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("groupby.html")

df.Cylinders = df.Cylinders.astype(str)
group = df.groupby('Cylinders')

source = ColumnDataSource(group)

cyl_cmap = factor_cmap('Cylinders', palette=Spectral5, 
factors=sorted(df.Cylinders.unique()))

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=group, title="Sales by Cylinder",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='Cylinders', top='2018', width=1, source=source,
   line_color=cyl_cmap, fill_color=cyl_cmap)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "some stuff"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is6zH.png

KeyError: 'Cylinders'
I cannot work out what is causing the error.

**EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED**

This is how the code should look:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("groupby.html")

df.origin = df.Cylinders.astype(str)
group = df.groupby('origin')

source = ColumnDataSource(group)

cyl_cmap = factor_cmap('origin', palette=Spectral5, 
factors=sorted(df.origin.unique()))

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=group, title="Sales by origin",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='origin', top='2018_max', width=1, source=source,
   line_color=cyl_cmap, fill_color=cyl_cmap)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "some stuff"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Comment: Your images are not showing up. In any case, it is always, *always* better to post actual text for code, rather than images of code. Images are not accessible to anyone with visual disability, and also cannot be easily copied to test out, which disincentivizes potential answerers.  Please add real code samples to your question.

Comment: Noted. I have edited the questions. Is this format more helpful?

Comment: You have created `grouped` but you don't use it anywhere. Here's an example in the documentation that does exactly what you want: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#pandas

Comment: Ok. I have edited my code to follow the example outlined in the documentation but I am still getting an error.

Comment: There is no `"Cylinders"` column in the `autompg` data set. Perhaps you mean `"cyl"`?

Comment: Thank you. I will post a solution using another variable as an example above.